# How to get NTP payload data bytes

Tags: python, byte, ntp

I have a piece of code to receive ntp timing

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM # For setting up the UDP packet.
import sys
import socket
import struct, time # To unpack the packet sent back and to convert the seconds to a string.

host = "pool.ntp.org"; # The server.
port = 123; # Port.
read_buffer = 1024; # The size of the buffer to read in the received UDP packet.
address = ( host, port ); # Tuple needed by sendto.
#data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'; # Hex message to send to the server.
data = [0x1b]

temp = [0x00 for i in range(47)]

data.extend(temp)

epoch = 2208988800 # Time in seconds since Jan, 1970 for UNIX epoch.

client = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM ); # Internet, UDP

client.sendto(bytes(data), address ); # Aend the UDP packet to the server on the port.

dataRx, address = client.recvfrom( read_buffer ); # Get the response and put it in data and put the send socket address into address.

t = struct.unpack( "!12I", dataRx)[ 10 ]; # Unpack the binary data and get the seconds out.

t -= epoch; # Calculate seconds since the epoch.

print("Time = {0}".format(time.ctime( t ))) # Print the seconds as a formatted string
```

based on the code given here:

https://github.com/lettier/ntpclient/blob/master/source/python/ntpclient.py

If I see the received data:

dataRx

b'\x1c\x02\x03\xe7\x00\x00\x02\x89\x00\x00\x00\x10\xc1O\xed\x0e\xe3\xecP\xea_u\x93\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe3\xecP\xf5\xd1D\x84\xdf\xe3\xecP\xf5\xd1F+\x1f'.

Question 1:

What are the 'xecP\xea_u' portion here in dataRx? Why non hex characters are present in the dataRx?

Question 2:

How to get the NTP timing bytes (64 bit) in the hexadecimal format?

Comment: Anything that can be represented in printable ASCII will be displayed as it is. In `\xecP` the character `P` is printable while `\xec` is not. You must use `dataRx.hex()` to see everything converted to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the NTP packet yourself, but recommend looking at the [ntplib](https://github.com/cf-natali/ntplib) python module which makes the NTP request, decodes the packet, etc. The ntplib request provides access to each field of the NTP response packet.

Getting the round-trip delay and time offset are already calculated based on the response. ntplib was created in 2009, and is still active and being maintained as of this answer.

If you're interested in the details, review the *ntplib.py* [source code](https://github.com/cf-natali/ntplib/blob/master/ntplib.py).

```python
import ntplib

client = ntplib.NTPClient()
server = 'pool.ntp.org'

resp = client.request(server, version=3)

print("offset", resp.offset)
print("delay", resp.delay)

print("orig_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.orig_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("recv_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.recv_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("tx_time  :", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.tx_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
print("dest_time:", datetime.utcfromtimestamp(resp.dest_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Output:

```
offset 0.004678010940551758
delay 0.06687116622924805

orig_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.410973
recv_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.449087
tx_time :  2021-06-10 19:07:52.449089
dest_time: 2021-06-10 19:07:52.477846
```